# How do I configure VS Code and Gradle to use generated Java code with the Gradle Protobuf plugin?

Tags: java, gradle, visual-studio-code, protocol-buffers, gradle-plugin

I'm trying to use Protobuf with Google's official Gradle plugin, with Gradle, in VS Code, in a small Java application to test out the workflow.

I can't get VS Code to recognize the generated Java source code, and in the terminal, I can't get Gradle to recognize the code either when I try to use Gradle to build the application.

VS Code displays this when I try to reference the generated code:

[image: VS Code, editing a Java file called App.java, where the text "Person" displays a red underline]

And Gradle displays the following error when I try to do a build:

```
> Task :app:compileJava FAILED
/home/mattgbi/vscode-gradle-protobuf-repro/app/src/main/java/vscode/gradle/protobuf/repro/App.java:14: error: cannot find symbol
        System.out.println(Person.class);
                           ^
  symbol:   class Person
  location: class App
1 error

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileJava'.
> Compilation failed; see the compiler error output for details.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 405ms
4 actionable tasks: 1 executed, 3 up-to-date
```

I understand that I need to add an import in `App.java` to use the `Person` class. But when I try to invoke the VS Code code completion tool to do that, as described above, the code completion fails to help me do that.

However, if I manually type out the import statement, VS Code says it can't find it.:

[image: VS Code error saying it can't find the package]

However, at this point, Gradle is able to use the import statement (even though VS Code rendered errors) and is able to complete the build:

```
> ./gradlew build

> Task :app:compileJava
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 1s
13 actionable tasks: 10 executed, 3 up-to-date
```

Here is a GitHub repo with a complete reproduction of the problem: https://github.com/mattwelke/repros/tree/main/vscode-gradle-protobuf-repro

Here are the steps I completed to encounter this issue:

1. Create project with `gradle init`. Choose "application" and leave all settings as default.
2. Follow instructions at https://github.com/google/protobuf-gradle-plugin to add the plugin to my project. Add "buildscript" part to top of `build.gradle` file, above `plugins` part of the file. Add line inside `plugins` part with `id "com.google.protobuf" version "0.8.18"`, below the line `id 'application'` in that part. Add block starting with `protobuf {` to bottom of the file, so that I can have Gradle download and use its own `protoc` binary.
3. Follow Java tutorial for Protobuf (https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/javatutorial), add the code that has `message Person {` near the top of the page to my application in the new file `app/src/main/proto/message.proto`.
4. Build with `./gradlew build` in VS Code terminal.
5. Observe source code generated into `app/build/generated/source` even though there were errors in the console saying `package com.google.protobuf does not exist`.
6. Add dependency `protobuf-java` (from https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.protobuf/protobuf-java) to `build.gradle` file under `dependencies` section of the file, so that my applications generated Java source code would be able to reference Protobuf library. Chose version 3.21.1 because it's the latest version as of right now. Added using `implementation` syntax.
7. Build application again with `./gradlew build` in VS Code terminal. Observed no errors this time in terminal.
8. Try to write source code in `App.java` (under `src`) that references the generated `Person` class. VS Code can't find it.
9. Try to build application again with `./gradlew build` in VS Code terminal. Gradle can't find the source code either.
10. Manually add import statement to `App.java`. Observe VS Code displaying errors about not being able to find the package still.
11. Try to build application again with `./gradlew build` in VS Code terminal. Gradle can't find the source code either. This time Gradle succeeds. Only issue remaining is how the IDE recognizes all the code (desired is that all code, including generated code, is recognized).

Comment: It seems that you didn't import a package. Can you show the source-code of `Person`?

Comment: Source code of Person.java: https://gist.github.com/mattwelke/5f3aae7611019f64123b7b1af63458e6 I chose not to include the generated code in the repro repo because in theory, the Gradle config should enable it to be reproduced exactly by a Gradle build for anyone cloning it.

Comment: Your advice reminded me I could have just manually typed in the import statement instead of relying on my IDE's code completion features to add it for me. I did that, and got further. Now, VS Code displays errors (as if it were unaware of the generated source code's existence), but Gradle is able to build the application. I edited the question to add this.

Comment: From the information you have provided it seems that the package is not seen as a resource by the project.

Comment: Yeah that sounds about right. I'm wondering now what the right thing to do is. Should I investigate how to change VS Code's configuration so that it sees the generated code, leaving the Protobuf plugin's config alone to have it put the generated code in its default destination. Or, should I leave VS Code alone and override the Protobuf plugin in `build.gradle` to change where it puts the source code? And if so, where should I put the source code? I think usually you wouldn't check in generated code. So I'm thinking if I went with the latter, I wouldn't put the generated code anywhere in `src`.

Comment: Have you installed the [Gradle Language Support](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=naco-siren.gradle-language) extension. Re-open the project after installing this extension and the Gradle extension will work.

Comment: This didn't help. I tried both this extension and the Microsoft Gradle extension. Both resulted in the same thing after I did the "Java: Clean Language Server Workspace" command, which appears to reload the projects (I got a popup in the bottom right corner saying it imported a Java project). I noticed too that there's a settings view I can access by clicking on the three dots under "JAVA PROJECTS" in the bottom left corner, then clicking "Configure Classpath". It displays a list of Sources with four entries: "src/main/java", "src/main/resources", "src/test/java", "src/test/resources".

Comment: I figured I'd try adding a fifth item to that list, which would be "app/build/generated/source/proto/main/java". But it won't let me edit that list and says "Read-only" next to "Sources". It also says "Below settings are only editable for projects without build tools. For Gradle project, please edit the entries in build.gradle." on that page. So I'm thinking that because I'm using Gradle, I'm meant to configure Gradle to recognize all the source code I intend to use in my app, including generated code.

Comment: I find it odd that this plugin doesn't configure this for me, so that any IDE using Gradle for the project would automatically pick up the source code. Do you think I should file a bug report with the plugin maintainers?

Comment: I got it to work. When I read the README for the plugin again, they describe how it adds a source set to Gradle as it is invoked. So I figured the problem is that it's only automatically adding the source set during the Gradle lifecycle, not when VS Code tries to parse the code to enable code completion. I added a source set whose `srcDir` was the directory the generated code goes into, then cleaned my Java workspace, and it worked. I'll add an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

My problem was that I didn't configure Gradle (via `build.gradle`) to include a new source set for where the generated code goes. VS Code reads the Gradle config when it detects it in order to set the classpath, and disables manually tweaking the class path when it detects it, so configuring Gradle is the only option for this.

Before adding source set to Gradle config:

[image: accessing classpath settings before adding source set to Gradle config 1]

[image: accessing classpath settings before adding source set to Gradle config 2]

[image: accessing classpath settings before adding source set to Gradle config 2 3]

After adding this to `build.gradle` at the bottom:

```
sourceSets {
  main {
    java {
      srcDir 'build/generated/source/proto/main/java'
    }
  }
}
```

[image: after adding to classpath via Gradle settings 1]

[image: after adding to classpath via Gradle settings 2]

Also, after deleting the `app/build` directory and running `./gradlew build` again, I found that I had to run the "delete workspace" command from the Java extension in order to get my workspace back to a healthy state, where the generated code was recognized by VS Code.

I realized this was the issue after reading the README for the plugin (https://github.com/google/protobuf-gradle-plugin) and reading their instructions on overriding the source sets. Being somewhat new to Gradle, I forgot about the significance of source sets. The README describes how the plugin dynamically sets up a source set for the generated code directory.

I figured that because VS Code isn't invoking any Gradle tasks to do Java code completion etc (I think it uses Eclipse tooling), but because it apparently uses the Gradle config to configure how it behaves with Java, the key to solving my problem was to manually tell VS Code about the new source set by specifying it explicitly in my `build.gradle` file.